# How to detect hotlink image when grabbing

Tags: php, image, google-api, hotlinking

Let say that i have an google search api for grabbing image. when i want to grab certain of image, using that api, i'll have many image from it. but some times i get hotlink image.

Is it possible to detect which one is the hotlink image programmatically, especially with PHP?

If it's possible, can you tell me how to do it?

Or is there a way to exclude hotlink image from google api result?

note: i'm not using wget to grab. i just want to detect which one is hotlink image.

Answer (score 1):

A hotlinked image will have a a fully qualified url.  All you have to do is compare the Host of the site you are grabbing images from.   In PHP you would use

```
 $siteHost = parse_url($site_url, PHP_URL_HOST);

 $imgHost = parse_url($img_src_url, PHP_URL_HOST);
 if($siteHost == $imgHost){grab_image($img_src_url);)
```

Comment: can it detect which one is hotlinked image and which one isn't?

Comment: You get the siteHost from the original URL returned by the API.

Comment: {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "link": "http://savoryeventcatering.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/IMG_1719.jpg",
   "displayLink": "savoryeventcatering.com",
   "snippet": "July 31, 2013 by Mckell",
   "htmlSnippet": "July 31, 2013 by Mckell",
   "mime": "image/jpeg",
   "image": {
    "contextLink": "http://savoryeventcatering.com/2013/07/meshing-elegant-and-vintage/img_1719/",

    "thumbnailLink": "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRdRHzVyFbNplD8F27LfujJDn04IC8vIvp-8UqU0yaB0muHvB95W0mjnCnv",
 }
},

Comment: it's one of google api json result. the value between hotlinked image and not have no different. so how your code work?

Comment: Get siteHost from the "link"  savoryeventcatering.com is the host.  Where as the thumbnail link the host is encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com